# Different transition timing for loading and hovering of the same property of the same object?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have an object that has a "page load animation" and I'm trying to add hover transition onto it. Both transitions use the same property, say for example background color. I need different timing for loading and hovering. How should I achieve this? Example below.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => document.querySelector("body").classList.add("loaded"));
```

```css
#test {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  transition: background-color 1s ease-in-out 1s;
  background-color: black;
}

body.loaded #test:hover {
  background-color: cyan;
}

body.loaded #test {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div align=center>
  <div id="test" style="display: inline-block;">Hello</div>
</div>
```

What exactly I want to achieve: I want the hover animation to be timed as `0.5s ease-in-out 0s` while keeping the loading animation at `1s ease-in-out 1s`. Both runs on `background-color` property.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `transition` on hover like this:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => document.querySelector("body").classList.add("loaded"));
```

```css
#test {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  transition: background-color 1s ease-in-out 1s;
  background-color: black;
}

body.loaded #test:hover {
  background-color: cyan;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
}

body.loaded #test {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div align=center>
  <div id="test" style="display: inline-block;">Hello</div>
</div>
```

**IMPORTANT**

`transition-delay` on `#test` which is 1s simply means delay the animation 1 second. But `transition-delay` on `#test:hover` means apply the delay only when you hover. It doesn't affect when you move your mouse away.

**EDIT**

If you want a different approach, you can also use pseudo-elements on `#test` which you can set a different timing on hovering.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => document.querySelector("body").classList.add("loaded"));
```

```css
#test {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  transition: background-color 1s ease-in-out 1s;
  background-color: black;
  position:relative;
}

body.loaded #test {
  background-color: transparent;
}

body.loaded #test:after{
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  z-index:-1;
}

body.loaded #test:hover::after {
  background-color: cyan;
  
}
```

```html
<div align=center>
  <div id="test" style="display: inline-block;">Hello</div>
</div>
```

**ALSO**, if you don't want the 'unhovering' animation, you can move the `transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;` to `body.loaded #test:hover::after` in order to only get the animation while 'hovering' not 'unhovering'.

Comment: But "unhovering" uses the undesired timing. Is there any way to apply the new timing "both directions"?

Comment: That suggests that it isn't possible (with simple CSS), right?

Comment: With only hovering, yes it is impossible. With simple CSS, you use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with CSS could be use a pseudo-element on  `#test` and delegate the *:hover* effect with different timing to it.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => document.querySelector("body").classList.add("loaded"));
```

```css
#test {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  transition: background-color 1s ease-in-out 1s;
  background-color: black;
  position:relative;
}

body.loaded #test {
  background-color: transparent;
}

body.loaded #test::after{
  background-color:#ffffff;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  z-index:-1;
}

body.loaded #test:hover::after {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div align=center>
  <div id="test" style="display: inline-block;">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative without adding pseudo elements. You can add an `animate` class and then `setTimeout` to add `loaded`. This will allow you to style the initial load different than hover.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  document.querySelector("body").classList.add("animate");
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector("body").classList.add("loaded");
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
#test {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  transition: background-color 1s ease-in-out 1s;
  background-color: black;
}

body.loaded #test{
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
}
body.loaded #test:hover {
  background-color: cyan;
}

body.animate #test, body.loaded #test {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div align=center>
  <div id="test" style="display: inline-block;">Hello</div>
</div>
```